# Mathematica `Integrate` evaluates some integrals only with some specific scaling factor

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Please consider the following integrals

```
G1[b_, q_] := NIntegrate[ E^(-(r^2/2)) Sqrt[π/2] Erf[(b r Sqrt[2]], {r, 0, q}]
G2[b_, q_] := NIntegrate[E^-r^2 Sqrt[π] Erf[b r  ], {r, 0, q/Sqrt[2]}]
```

These two integrals are related by a simple substitution $r \to \sqrt 2 r$. Therefore, the answer should be the same. For example,

```
(G1[1.5, 0.5]/G2[1.5, 0.5]) - 1 
 -1.11022*10^-16 (*answer*)
```

However, if I try to find the indefinite integrals, only one of them returns a non-trivial result, i.e.,

```
 Integrate[E^-r^2 Sqrt[π] Erf[b r  ], r]
```

is evaluated to

```
 1/2 π (1 - Erf[b r] (-1 + Erfc[r]) + 4 OwenT[Sqrt[2] b r, 1/b])
```

while the other integral

```
 Integrate[E^(-(r^2/2)) Sqrt[π/2] Erf[(b r  )/Sqrt[2]], r]
```

returns the unevaluated input.

I am aware that the built-in `Integrate` is a complicated beast to be understood. However, still it looks a bit strange to see Mathematica fails to notice such a simple substitution.

Additionally, is there any way to force `Integrate` to consider such substitution?

Comment: The integration is prolly done by pattern-matching, and *Mathematica* fails to notice that they are more or less the same.

Comment: Is the first function meant to be `Erf[(b r/Sqrt[2]]` rather than `Erf[(b r Sqrt[2]]`.... If so is there a problem?

Comment: @Ramble No, the equation given in the question is correct. Basically they are equivalent integrals by a simple substitution $r \to r \sqrt{2}$. However, Mathematica only evaluates one of the indefinite integrals. I am wondering why Mathematica fails to notice such a simple relation.