# How to reparametrize a probability density function

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I have this probability density function (pdf)
    $$
f(t)=\beta \left[\left(\frac{t}{\eta_1}\right)^{\beta} + \left(\frac{t}  
{\eta_2}\right)^{\beta}  \right]t^{-1}e^{- \left(\frac{t}{\eta_1}
\right)^{\beta} - \left(\frac{t}{\eta_2}\right)^{\beta}}
$$
then using *Mathematica 10 (student version)*, I obtain
    $$
\int_0^\infty f(t) dt= 1.
$$
But when I reparametrize $\alpha_i = \left(\frac{t}{\eta_i}\right)^{\beta}$,  $i=1,2$, 
    $$
g(t) = \beta (\alpha_1 + \alpha_2)t^{-1}e^{- (\alpha_1 + \alpha_2)},
$$
I obtain an error warning:

> Integrate::idiv: "Integral of 1/t does not converge on {0,∞}.

pdf:

```
model[t_, β_, η1_, η2_] := \
β  t^-1   ((t/η1)^β + (t/η2)^β) E^(-(t/\
η1)^β - (t/η2)^β)

Integrate[model[t, β, η1, η2], {t, 0, ∞}, 
 Assumptions -> {β > 0, η1 > 0, η2 > 0}]
```

latter code is equal 1.

pdf reparametrized:

```
model2[t_, β_, α1_, α2_] := β  t^-1   (α1 + α1) E^(- α1 - α2)
```

and when

```
Integrate[model2[t, β, α1, α2], {t, 0, ∞}, 
Assumptions -> {β > 0, α1 > 0, α2 > 0}]
```

I obtain this error warning:

> Integrate::idiv: "Integral of 1/t does not converge on {0,∞}.

Comment: Please use code, rather than $\LaTeX$.

Comment: [Similar](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/133591/mathematica-integrate-evaluates-some-integrals-only-with-some-specific-scaling)

Comment: @Feyre, Where am I wrong? I'm novice in to use Mathematica software.

Comment: I do not get the error, in fact your second code evaluates to `1` too, I suggest quitting your kernel and trying again.

Comment: @Feyre There's an error in the second code: there's `model` while it should be `model2`.

Comment: Your pdf $f(t)$ is a function of a random variable $T$. You say you are re-parameterising, but $t$ is not parameter - it is a variable. The substitution you have made ---  $\alpha_i = \left(\frac{t}{\eta_i}\right)^{\beta}$ -- are not valid, because $t$ is not a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make the substitutions back into the integrand, so Mathematica can know what the definitions of `α1` and `α2` are.

```
model2[t_, β_, α1_, α2_] := β(α1 + α2)/t E^(-α1 - α2)
   Integrate[
     model2[t, β, α1 /. α1 -> (t/n1)^β, α2 /. α2 -> (t/n2)^β], {t, 0, ∞}, 
     Assumptions -> {β > 0, n1 > 0, n2 > 0}]
```

> `1`

Comment: @Marco, "I can't have $\eta_i$ in my outcomes" - that's kind of muddled; you do realize that $\eta_i$ is constant, while $\alpha_i$ is dependent on $t$, no? Thus, your mean expression cannot involve $\alpha_i$ as you have presented it.

Comment: @Marco. All these comments should be made as update to your question so they will addressed to the community at large, not just to me. They are not really comments on my answer as far as I can tell.